# dealing with images of varying heights for twitter bootstrap carousel and link for images in carousel

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, carousel

What is the most effective way to deal with images of varying heights?

a) I have many images and several of them are taller than the rest. I'd like to make them restricted to the area of the carousel. But, if I define the carousel dimensions explicitly (like .carousel { width: 500px; height: 500px; } ) then I lose the auto-resizing that bootstrap does, which is crucial for making the site look good on mobile sites.

b) Is is possible to provide hyperlink/link for images in twitter bootstrap?

Anyone know how?

Answer (score 2):

`img { width: 100%; }` on the image and `#carousel_container_id_here { max-height: XXXpx; overflow-y: hidden; }`

Note that it will clip the images that exceed the `max-height`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just specify `max-height` e.g. `.carousel { max-height: 500px; }`. That way, re-sizing should work and the design won't break either.